# I need to migrate from jersey 1.x to 2.13 , how many packages name has been changed?

Tags: java, jersey, glassfish, migration

I need to migrate from jersey 1.x to 2.13 , I want the a list of how many packages name has been changed ? Also  from package com.sun.jersey.httpContext  I was able to use "httpContext" but after upgrading I am getting error as httpContext is not there in 2.13 or may b I am not using it properly. Need help in this .

The official documentation is not helping me as it didn't mention about all dependencies needed .

Let me know if further clarification about the question needed .